# Unable to connect to MongoDB and MySQL by Spring App using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose.yml` like below to create containers. I'm new in it, and I'm trying to create one nginx container, tomcat container with spring app and two database containers (mongo and mysql). On Debian server Spring app works, so I think the problem is with configuration of docker containers.

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    links:
     - web
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  web:
    image: tomcat:8.0-jre8
    links:
      - mongo
      - mysql
    volumes:
     - ./bint.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/bint.war
     - ./tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml

  mongo:
    image: mongo:2.7
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```

I can connect to mongo and mysql by tools like workbench and robomongo just using `localhost` and default ports, but spring app couldn't. I'm working on OSX 10.11.5.

```
Docker version 1.12.0-rc2, build 906eacd, experimental
docker-compose version 1.8.0-rc1, build 9bf6bc6
docker-machine version 0.8.0-rc1, build fffa6c9
```

MySql stacktrace

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    web_1    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
web_1    |  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
web_1    |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
web_1    |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
web_1    |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
web_1    |  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
web_1    |  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
web_1    |  at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:214)
web_1    |  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
web_1    |  ... 58 more
```

Mongo stacktrace

```
web_1    | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp://172.17.0.3:27017"
web_1    |  at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:77)
web_1    |  at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:54)
web_1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1033)
web_1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
web_1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
web_1    |  ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spring app will be able to connect using mongo:27017 and mysql:3306.
It will not be reachable using localhost:27017 and localhost:3306.

The other option you have is to docker-compose version 2, then all containers by default will share the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I know Docker should be enough using links to access another container on the default network created. I would suggest trying using the hostname attribute on all containers with the same name of the container just to be sure. I think that might help with the MySQL error - Unfortunately we do not see the connection url in the stack trace to be sure is trying using the appropriate hostname -

For the MongoDB error, I'm facing the same issue. for some reason Docker is changing the defined port 27017 into `tcp://172.17.0.3:27017` that is the reason of the String conversion exception. there might be some attribute reader in spring that is getting from application.properties or some other env variable the mongo db port but is getting it wrong. I am investigating why that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

ok, found somewhere a work around for the mongodb problem... it is a little bit different from what I had and the guy explainig had. we had the mongodb definition on docker-composer.yml as

mongodb:
   image: mongo
   etc....

It seems the way links work or used to work is using some env vars and some how this end up overwriting a spring param mongodb.port or mongo.port.

MONGO_PORT='tcp://172.17.0.3:27017'

The thing is the workaround is to rename the container I used mdb: etc... and the problem was gone.

Hope this helps. will try to dig more on this to see what is actually doing